# Caching? Large Query performance for multiple, optional filters

Tags: performance, caching, search, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm trying to figure out my options for a large query which is taking a somewhat long but sensible amount of time considering what it does.  It has many joins and has to be searched against for up to a predefined number of parameters.  Some of these parameter values are predefined (select box) while some are a free-form text box (unfortunately `LIKE` with prefixed and suffixed wildcards).  The data sets returned are large and the filter options are very likely to be changed frequently.  The order of the result sets are also controlled by the user.  Additionally, user access must be restricted to only results the user is authorized to.  This authorization is handled as part of a baseline `WHERE` clause which is applied regardless of the chosen filters.

I'm not really looking for query optimization advice as I've already reviewed the query and examined/optimized the query plan as much as I can given my requirements.  I'm more interested in alternative solutions intended for after the query has been optimized.  Outside of trying to break up the query into separate smaller bits (which unfortunately is not an acceptable solution), I can only think of two options.  But, I don't think they are a good fit for this situation.

1. Caching first came to my mind, but I don't think it is viable based
   on how likely the filters will vary and the large datasets returned.
2. From my research, options such as ElasticSearch and Solr would not be the
   right fit either as the data sets can be manipulated my multiple programs and these data stores would quickly become outdated.

Are there other options to improve the perceived performance of a search feature with these requirements?

Comment: DB2 for i already does caching, and a home grown caching solution on top of what the db is already doing rarely improves things. If the SQL is already optimized as much as it can be, I suspect that means you have run it through visual explain and tried adding recommended indexes, and minimizing full table scans. And I am guessing that you have dealt with joins that could potentially artificially explode the temporary result set to millions of rows. So what do you really want?

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question to include the tables, joins, and the fields involved in the where. Besides standard indexes, DB2 for i offers EVI indexes.  Also, DB2 Omnifind might be of use depending on what fields you're using `LIKE`  on.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I'm already familiar with the visual explain feature and have already used it extensively for this.  I've also reviewed the recommended indexes I find most of the time it recommends way too much.  I've limited the recommonded indexes to those used as part of a join field and the where clause as it made updates slower.  The only full table scans I get are due to the `LIKE` clauses, but my users "need" that.  What I'm asking is if there are other after-optimization methods such as caching I can look into.

Comment: @Charles I'm not looking for query optimization help, I'm familiar with that process and have already took care of that part.  I'm already making use of EVI Indexes where the index adviser suggested (I didn't blindly create all of them though).  However, I will look into DB2 Omnifind.  I have never heard of that and if that is supposed to help with `LIKE` clauses then it may be what I was looking for.

Comment: What OS version? How large would such a "cache" be? How much spare DASD is available?

Comment: The 1980's called they want their search design back.  Absolutely aughful design  Users will say it's dificult and time consuming to use. Start over before its too late.  Research How to I implement search engine type assist web pages.

Comment: @user2338816 I'm on V7R2.  I'm not sure of the size of the would be cache.  The final result sets returned are only a couple of thousand records, but the filter parameters will likely never be the same.  Can caching still be a viable option if this is so?  The system has about 1.4TB available.

Comment: @danny117 It was my understanding that search engine type of searches were not ideal for situations in which a user MUST be restricted to results only they are authorized to.  This is an absolute requirement as we can't have users viewing other users results.   Additionally there are old legacy programs (written in RPG/CL) which also manipulate this data outside of this particular app.  To my knowledge these languages cannot interact with ElasticSearch or Solr datastores.  Am I misunderstanding these restrictions of search engine type of searches?

Comment: DB2 Omnifind is a full text search engine.  Start here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/OmniFind%20for%20IBM%20i  It's not designed to "help with `LIKE`", but it allows for web-type searches integrated into your app's SQL search.  If you're using `LIKE` with a 30 character text field, it's probably not going to help.  But if you're using `LIKE` with a 1000 character VARCHAR field, Omnifind is probably a better choice.

Comment: D.lanza38 it's a bad 1980s design.  Edit your question if you want to restrict user access.

Comment: @danny117 Thank you for responding, I appreciate the help.  I will update the question to specify that user access must be restricted.  Given the fact that user access must be restricted, is there an alternative to this bad 1980s design?

Comment: @Charles After looking into Omnifind it may very well be what I'm looking for.  I won't be able to have it installed until next week the earliest though.  So I won't be able to test the performance difference until then.  It's a huge plus that is free and doesn't require external datastore maintenance besides the manual re-indexing.  Thank's a bunch!  I'll update once I am able to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough information about your tables and queries for a concrete solution.

As mentioned in a comment by @jmarkmurphy, DB2 and IBM i does it's own "caching".  I agree that it's unlikely you'd be able to improve upon it when dealing with large and varied results sets.   But you need to make sure you're using what's provided by IBM.  For example, if using SQL embedded in RPGLE, make sure you don't have `set option CLOSQLCSR=*ENDMOD`.  Also check the settings in QAQQINI you're using.

You've mentioned using Visual Explain and building some of the requested indexes.  That's a good start.  But as the queries are run in production, keep an eye on the plan cache, index usage and the advised indexes.

Lastly, you mentioned that you're seeing full table scans do to the use of `LIKE '%SOMETHING%'`.  Again, without details of the columns and data involved, it's a guess as to what may be useful.  As suggested in my comment, [Omnifind for IBM i](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/OmniFind%20for%20IBM%20i) may be an improvement.

However, Omnifind is **NOT** and improved `LIKE`.  Omnifind is designed to handle linguistic searches.  From the article [i Can … Find a Needle in a Haystack using OmniFind Text Search Server for DB2 for i](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0f43236a-ee97-4572-b609-5102b118e9be&ps=25):

```
SELECT story_id FROM story_library.story_table 
WHERE CONTAINS(story_doc, 'blind mouse') = 1;
```

> This query result will include matches that we’d expect from a typical search engine.  The search is case insensitive, and linguistic variations on the search words will be matched. In other words, the previous query will indicate a match for documents that contain “Blind Mice.” In a similar manner, a search for “bad wolves” would return documents that contained “the Big Bad Wolf.”

Comment: I have not forgotten about this,  I'm still trying to get Omnifind installed.  However I did manage to figure out the query execution took ms while the fetching of the rows took forever.  I was using some views in conjunction with an `order by` and the views were complicated enough to prevent it from using indexes for the `order by`.  This caused it to create an entire hash table before returning the first record.  So this sped up the overall performance greatly.